# Bypass database constraints during record deletion

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have around 20 mapping tables which refer to a single table.

The single table being referenced is,

---

```
field (
  id integer,
  value char
)
```

The mapping tables are as,

---

```
employee_field_map (
   employee_id integer references employee(id),
   field_id references field(id)
)

dept_field_map (
   dept_id integer references dept(id),
   field_id references field(id)
)
```

and similar additional 18 mapping tables.

Now if I want to delete number of records from the `field` table where `field.id = employee_field_map.field_id` it takes very long amount of time because there are 20 mapping tables which refer to the `field` table; And for each of that mapping table a constraint violation check is performed before deleting a record from the `field` table.
A `field` table rcord will always be referenced by only one of the mapping table at a time.
In above scenario before deleting a record from `field` table of course the corresponding record in `employee_field_map` table is deleted first. So I know for sure that none of the mapping table contains a reference to the `field` table record being deleted. So is there a way to tell the database engine not to perform those constraint checks when the delete on `field` table is being performed?
Disabling the constraints is not an option unfortunately. Please advise.

Comment: Is there an index on each fk columns in all 20 tables referring to fields table?

Comment: Yes, there is an index in all mapping tables on field_id column that refers to the field table.

Comment: Are you sure? An existence check on an indexed column will take no time at all (especially if there is no data that would cause the constraint violation). If you are experiencing this delete take any time then you've probably missed an index.

Comment: @ivish Keep in mind that those constraints have purposes for their existence. One of those being to *prevent you from doing something you should not do*. Even if it takes a couple of minuets constraint validation is **preventing data corruption** in your database.  That protection is well the cost, especially if it prevents several hours or days on data reconstruction.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each of the mapping tables has an index on `field_id`, then the lookups should not be expensive.

I am wondering why you are not declaring them using cascading delete foreign key references:

```
employee_field_map (
   employee_id integer references employee(id),
   field_id references field(id) on delete cascade
);
```

Nothing in your data model is saying that the field is in only one mapping table.  In fact, I don't see why things are broken out the way they are.  Presumably there is a reason for breaking the fields apart like this instead of just having a "type" column in the `fields` table.

Comment: It's an existing database system that I am working on. There are currently no on-delete cascades. But even if on-delete cascaded are added the constraint violation checks will still be performed on all mapiing tables when deleting a record from field table, right?

Comment: @ivish . . . I wouldn't really worry about the overhead *if there is an index on the referring column*.